# How to extract tags at the same level with XML.extract?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

with this query I take everything inside the tag ROW.
But I would like to take everything expect the tag <field_without_interest>.

```
select xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
).extract( '/ROWSET/ROW' ) .getstringval() p#
from dual;
```

I can select the sub tags

```
select xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <field_without_interest>f</field_without_interest>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
).extract( '/ROWSET/ROW/PERSON_NUMBER' ) .getstringval() p#
from dual;
```

But I'm selectioning only the half the tags that I am interested in.

Is there a way to write `extract( '/ROWSET/ROW/PERSON_NUMBER' AND '/ROWSET/ROW/LOAN_1' )`
Or
`extract( '/ROWSET/ROW/ except'/ROWSET/ROW/field_without_interest' )`

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4050751d233046382dc0a33b325d7a9c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XMLQUERY` and FLOWR.

If you only want the first `ROW` then:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         'copy $NEWHTML := /ROWSET/ROW[1]
         modify (
           for $i in $NEWHTML/field_without_interest
           return delete node $i
         )
         return $NEWHTML/*'
         PASSING xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <field_without_interest>f</field_without_interest>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
)
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getStringVal() AS interested_elements
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | INTERESTED_ELEMENTS |
> | --- |
> | <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> |

---

Or, if you want the entire `ROWSET`, you can use:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         'copy $NEWHTML := .
         modify (
           for $i in $NEWHTML/ROWSET/ROW/field_without_interest
           return delete node $i
         )
         return $NEWHTML'
         PASSING xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <field_without_interest>f</field_without_interest>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
)
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getStringVal() AS interested_elements
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | INTERESTED_ELEMENTS |
> | --- |
> | <?xml version="1.0"?><ROWSET><ROW><PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1></ROW><ROW><PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1></ROW></ROWSET> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=038b1cba0105595d20cdb45128883d00)*